# I am trying to install Ubuntu but all I get is a "no signal" message on my monitor

Tags: 12.04, installation, 13.04, dvd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu (I've tried 12.04 Server, Desktop and 13.04 Desktop). I burn the image file to DVD, but on booting, all I get is the screen with the man in the circle and the keyboard, the DVD drive light flickers for a bit then I get the "no signal" message.

My system is:
AMD A8-3850, 8Gb RAM, ASRock A75M mobo, Kingston 60Gb SSD and LG HD DVD/BluRay combo. If it matters, I am using HDMI out. Monitor is a Viewsonic 13".

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Remember to [set your BIOS to boot from the CD/DVD drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD#BIOS_is_not_set_to_boot_from_CD_or_DVD_drive).

Comment: I've done that - although now that I think of it, how should I have formatted the SSD prior to installing Ubuntu?

Comment: @David There's no need to format the SSD before installing Ubuntu or do anything different except that in the installer you should select the external HD when asked to choose which device to install in.

Comment: I'm glad you said that - as you may have gathered, you are dealing with a complete Ubuntu novice here! When I booted, I noticed that if I could move the cursor down before it sped past the screen giving me the option of (something like) "Running Ubuntu/Running Ubuntu in Recovery Mode/MemTest/MemTest in Recovery Mode" to running in Recovery Mode, and I update all the packages, it gets to a log on screen, and "welcome to Ubuntu 12.04". However, it also says that I need to restart, and after a restart via the restart button, I get the same "no signal" problem. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Well, Recovery Mode can be used if your system is broken and doesn't boot, memtest is a program that checks your memory.

Comment: @David have you installed Ubuntu and then it doesn't boot or you are unable to start the installer from the DVD? (have you installed Ubuntu or not?)

Comment: I was running Win 7 with no problems, tired of it and successfully installed Ubuntu. We were forced to move state, and I had to dismantle the PC. Long story short, I ended up installing Win 7 again, and now that I want to change the PC to a media server, I want Ubuntu back, only this time I am having problems. Is it connected to the UEFI firmware of the mobo?